# Which Protestant churches as of today officially recognize homosexual marriage unions?

Tags: protestantism, homosexuality

Which Protestant churches as of today officially recognize homosexual marriage unions? Is there any such information available?

Comment: This is kind of listy. Is there a reason you want to know?

Comment: A lot of Protestant organisations are highly decentralised. Individual congregations may differ. It would be very hard to come up with a comprehensive list.

Comment: @waxeagle - I want to find out which Protestant churches do this, so that I could later ask them here directly about their basis in the Bible for this.

Comment: I don't think this question is unreasonable. Yes it sounds 'listy', but we know the answer is going to be a manageable number of churches, and it's likely that a reference can be found that lists most of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are the same churches that approve ordination of lesbians. You can find a list [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordination_of_LGBT_Christian_clergy#section_1).

When reading the list keep in mind that some traditional churches have a wide range of different churches under the same umbrella.  For example, one Lutherian or Anglican church might openly preach against homosexuality of any kind, while just a few blocks away, another might ordain a lesbian as their rector or senior pastor!

Comment: Hello Mike. Thank you for your answer and for the link.